# Webscraping with Python of a dynamic website (configurator)

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, dynamic

I was able to reduce the data I like to scrap to this:

```
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" for="product_1234_rentMonth_2">
<span>                    36 Monate
                                            <span>
                            +200 €
                        </span>
</span>
```

I like to extract the two -values 36 and +200.

I tried the following:

```
vehicle_config = []
    for result in results:
        #print(result)
        collect = result.find('label', class_='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary', attrs={'span': 'text'}) 
        vehicle_config.append(collect)
```

But I just recieve 'None'.

Maybe someone is able to answer my question.

Thanks.

```
<label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" for="product_1234_rentMonth_2">
<span>                    36 Monate
                                            <span>
                            +200 €
                        </span>
</span>
```

I like to extract the two -values 36 and +200.

I tried the following:

```
vehicle_config = []
    for result in results:
        #print(result)
        collect = result.find('label', class_='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary', attrs={'span': 'text'}) 
        vehicle_config.append(collect)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is that your selection `result.find('label', class_='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary', attrs={'span': 'text'})` is not working so it is `None`.

Simplest approach would be to skip the `, attrs={'span': 'text'}` because your element do not have this:

```
result.find('label', class_='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary')
```

To extract the texts to a `list` for postprocessing you could use `stripped_strings`:

```
list(result.find('label', class_='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary').stripped_strings)

-> ['36 Monate', '+200 €']
```

or alternative selection with `css selectors`:

```
list(result.select_one('label.btn.btn-sm.btn-outline-secondary').stripped_strings)

-> ['36 Monate', '+200 €']
```

To get only the digits:

```
import re
[int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', result.find('label', class_='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary').text)]

-> [36, 200]
```

Comment: `vehicle_config = []
for result in results:
   collect = result.find('span').get_text(strip=True).split('+')
vehicle_config.append(collect)`

delivers

`[['6 Monate'], ['24 Monate', '150\xa0€'], ['18 Monate', '200\xa0€'], ['12 Monate', '300\xa0€'], ['1.250 km'], ['1.750 km', '100\xa0€'], ['2.000 km', '150\xa0€'], ['2.500 km', '250\xa0€']]`